# Duplicates show as "on hold" in the weekly/monthly list of questions

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, title

I'm not sure if I'm seeing a bug or regression here, since I *believe* it worked at some point… anyway. If you look at this [list of questions](https://superuser.com/?tab=week):

> [image]

The [second question here](https://superuser.com/questions/679048/how-to-make-ctrlaltdel-switch-directly-to-task-manager) is actually a duplicate, so shouldn't it be marked as `[duplicate]` in the title?

Interestingly, when I [search for `duplicate:1`](https://superuser.com/search?q=duplicate:1), I get the right titles.

Comment: It seems like it shows "on hold" only on home page only (i.e. [month](http://superuser.com/?tab=month), [week](http://superuser.com/?tab=week) etc tab on homepage). It looks fine on [questions page](http://superuser.com/questions?page=16&sort=active&pagesize=50) (find this question on this page).

Comment: Ah, got it! That's why I was so confused.